# getting an images from a text with preg_matc, replace, regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

**first**: sorry for my bad english but ı hope ı will explain my problem.

ı have a value its including to many image names.

**like this**: some.jpganother.pngother.gifsomesome.jpg....

ı need to seperate this image names.

```
some.jpg
another.png
other.gif
somesome.jpg
```

ı am searching but still ı dont have enough answer.

**my solutions are:**

```
regexp_substr('some.jpganother.pngother.gif', '[a-z0-9/]+.jpg');

preg_match_all("@([a-z0-9-]+).(jpg|gif|png)@i",'some.jpganother.pngother.gif',$a);
```

thank you.

Comment: Why are these image names getting concatenated without spacing?

Comment: I'd suggest as well, to check if the value could be adapted, in having the filenames separated clearly. This would prevent the efforts in developing and running the separating through regexp magic a lot. Since as soon a filename would be "bad.gif.png" a clear separating might become impossible.

Comment: What is the problem with your solution? The `preg_match_all` search worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that the preg_match_all() in your example should work, but here's an example that should work better - it doesn't limit the characters that can be in the filename before the extension and it doesn't capture a bunch of extra stuff.

```php
preg_match_all('/.*?\.(?:png|gif|jpe?g)/', 'some.jpganother.pngother.gif', $matches);
print_r($matches);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => some.jpg
            [1] => another.png
            [2] => other.gif
        )

)
```